# strtok_r behaviour and pointers

Tags: c, c99

I have a piece of code that when compiled with GCC-4.5.1 for x86_64 fails for the following warning:

```
error: ctx1 may be used uninitialized in this function
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
int args_tokenize(struct kvargs *kvlist, const char *params)
{
   char *str, *ctx1;
   str = strdup(params);
   ...

   while ((str = strtok_r(str, KVARGS_PAIRS_DELIM, &ctx1)) != NULL) {
     /* here goes the logic */
     ...
   }

   return 0;
}
```

So for some reason strtok_r() doesn't like that ctx1 isn't initialized, although according to 'man strtok_r':

> The  saveptr    argument  is  a pointer to a char * variable that
>   is used internally by    strtok_r() in order to maintain context
>   between successive  calls  that    parse the same string.
>
> On  the  first call to strtok_r(), str should point to the string
>   to be    parsed, and the value of saveptr is ignored.  In subsequent
>   calls,  str    should  be  NULL,  and  saveptr  should be unchanged
>   since the previous    call.

So as I understand it, it should not care if 'saveptr' has a sane value or not. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think the compiler knows as much about `strtok_r` as the man page does.

Comment: It seems like this should just be a warning, not an error. Also, you're not setting `str` to `NULL` on subsequent calls, as you're supposed to.

Comment: This is a known "bug", depending on whom you ask. It has been referenced [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26634) and [here, with a possible alternative.](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg22773.html)

Comment: 1) Does `char *ctx1 = NULL;` quiet the warning/error?  2) Looks like the re-assignment of `str` looses the original value of `str` for eventual freeing.